# how to select listboxitem when it has child like groupbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, listboxitem

i have following item template for a listbox

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBoxItem >
                        <GroupBox Header="{Binding}" Width="150" IsEnabled="False" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#25A0DA">
                            <GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label  Content="{Binding Name}" MinWidth="100" Width="130" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" Background="#25A0DA" Margin="0,0,-10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                    </Grid>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GroupBox.HeaderTemplate>

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Content="{Binding ID}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding MajorName}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </GroupBox>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

when i run app ,every things is ok , but when i select an item,
the groupbox will be selected and its not what i want.
**how can i select only listboxitem  when i select an item ?**
thanks in advance

Comment: its done , i just removed listboxitem tag

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want multiple items to be selected in a ListBox, just set the SelectionMode property of listbox to **Single**